# Profile is not an "iOS App Store" profile

Tags: ios, ios-provisioning, xcode9

Using **Xcode 9**.

1. Working on app store build validation.
2. Created an app with app store profile.
3. Archived successfully
4. Trying to validate build in
   Organizer, I am getting the following error on selecting the
   profile.

[image]
This is the same profile used to archive and it is an app store profile.

2 Queries

1. How to identify a profile if it is ad-hoc or app store
2. Why did this happen?Pretty sure this is an appstore profile.

Answer (score 5):

Just had the same issue

All you need to do is to delete your provisioning profile and create another one on [Apple Developer site](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/profile/).

#### Queries:

- 1) The only info we have about it is the Development or Distribution label on the profile itself
- 2) I can't say it for sure, but maybe Xcode 9 signing doesn't recognize old profiles the same way it once did.

Comment: having same issue, but company not allowing to regenerate profile.
any solution

Answer (score 3):

If all else fails try using the Application Loader. I almost just default to the Application Loader nowadays with how ridiculously buggy the Xcode upload process is version after version.

Comment: Thank, try to upload adhoc build using XCode but cannot success and got the error "Profile is not an iOS App Store profile". Now I have to use Application Loader.

Comment: After uploading successfully, I got email from Apple states that "Invalid Swift Support - The SwiftSupport folder is missing.". So weird.

Answer (score 2):

I think you selected the Ad Hoc option to get the .ipa file. Select the App Store option to get the .ipa file, then use the Application loader to submit the .ipa file.

In my case, I'm getting emails like this...

```
Missing beta entitlement - Your app does not include the beta-reports-active entitlement. If you intend to distribute this build via TestFlight for beta testing, please re-build this app with an App Store Distribution provisioning profile. Do not use ad-hoc profiles.

After you’ve corrected the issues, you can use Xcode or Application Loader to upload a new binary to iTunes Connect.

Regards,
The App Store team
```

Then I changed the option from Ad Hoc to [App Store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWGYD.png).

Answer (score -1):

In my case I always trying to avoid revoke Apple `cert`, because I share it with different developers from my company.

So I follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46881875/6705161) which suggest to downgrade `Xcode` -> I check version `9.0.1` and unfortunately I have still same error message.

**But I've installed additionally `8.3.3`** - it works correctly with uploading to Apple store.

*Update:* I move back into Xcode `9.1`installed directly from App Store, because I have problem with run `ionic cordova build`

So at this moment I am using two Xcode versions:

- `9.1` - for testing and creating builds - directly in Application
- `8.3.3` - for uploading build to [iTunnes Connect](https://www.google.pl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi85Zvg8-bXAhUGHRQKHSFgDpgQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fitunesconnect.apple.com%2F&usg=AOvVaw27p89MqqyemT0L6sincpW9) - beside run from different folder

I hope this is temporary situation.

---

**[Update]**

After some time I realized that my Provisioning Profile start with `XC` which is not accepted by `Xcode 9+`. After refresh all my Provisioning Profiles (*avoiding `XC` in name*) - I can finally use `Xcode 9+`.

Maybe this can be also useful for those who straggle this problem.