# Xcode 9.0.1 App Distribution Procedure is Changed

Tags: ios, xcode, build, app-store, xcode9

Recently I have upgraded my Xcode to Xcode 9.1. After that when I try to publish my app, Xcode is not allowing to select the distribution profile I created for ad-hoc. Saying that

> Profile is not an IOS App store profile

Please let me know if there is a change in App distribution procedure with respect to Xcode 9.1

Comment: Are you using automatic signing and profiling? You might need to delete your provisioning profiles on the portal and create new ones.

Comment: I created the new one for the Adhoc. But still the issue persists. If I create App store profile, it continues archiving and validating. I doubt if apple has made some changes the way we distribute the apps? No more Adhoc profile?

Comment: FYI make sure you are not using Beta Xcode 9.0.1. Beta Xcode's builds are not acceptable by AppStore.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Profile is not an "iOS App Store" profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46475375/profile-is-not-an-ios-app-store-profile)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got a clue from this apple documentation about an important change the way we publish the app to appstore.
 https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1814/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40014030. There it talks about automatic code signing. This makes it different from the older versions of Xcode.  In order to publish from xcode version 9 onwards, we have to prefer automatic code signing from the project settings. That way apple made publishing lot easier. You don't have to change profiles everytime between development and distribution.

I have development and distribution profiles created in my apple developer account. From the Xcode, In the General tab Signing section select the Team.  Xcode9.0.1 look out for the appropriate profile from the available ones and proceeds with the publishing.

Comment: FYI: Automatic code signing creates a new profile, which you cannot use on other systems, where simultaneous development activities going on, in same/single project. Prefer your own created profile.

Answer (score 5):

**Xcode tool you are using (Xcode 9.1 beta) is not a stable version of Xcode Tool as on today, so It must/will not allow you publish/submit a build on app store.**

> Only stable version of Xcode tool can create/upload a build on store.

You must use anyone of stable version of Xcode tool from following reference links:

> **Xcode 9**
>
> - [Xcode 9.4.1](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/)
>     
>    [- (Command Line Tool (Xcode 9.4.1) - for macOS 10.13)](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.13_for_Xcode_9.4.1/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.13_for_Xcode_9.4.1.dmg)
> - [Xcode 9.4](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/)
>     
>    [- (Command Line Tool (Xcode 9.4) - for macOS 10.13)](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.13_for_Xcode_9.4/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.13_for_Xcode_9.4.dmg)
> - [Xcode 9.3.1](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/)
> - [Xcode 9.3](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/)
>     
>    [- (Command Line Tool (Xcode 9.3) - for macOS 10.13)](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.13_for_Xcode_9.3/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.13_for_Xcode_9.3.dmg)
> - [Xcode 9.2](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/)
>     
>    [- (Command Line Tool (Xcode 9.2) - for macOS 10.13)](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.13_for_Xcode_9.2/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.13_for_Xcode_9.2.dmg)
>     
>    [- (Command Line Tool (Xcode 9.2) - for macOS 10.12)](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.12_for_Xcode_9.2/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.12_for_Xcode_9.2.dmg)
> - [Xcode 9.1](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/)
>     
>    [- (Command Line Tool (Xcode 9.1) - for macOS 10.13)](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.13_for_Xcode_9.1/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.13_for_Xcode_9.1.dmg)
>     
>    [- (Command Line Tool (Xcode 9.1) - for macOS 10.12)](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.12_for_Xcode_9.1/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.12_for_Xcode_9.1.dmg)
> - [Xcode 9.0.1](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/)
>     
>    [- (Command Line Tool (Xcode 9.0.1) - for macOS 10.13)](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.13_for_Xcode_9.0.1/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.13_for_Xcode_9.0.1.dmg)
>     
>    [- (Command Line Tool (Xcode 9.0.1) - for macOS 10.12)](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.12_for_Xcode_9.0.1/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.12_for_Xcode_9.0.1.dmg)
> - [Xcode 9.0](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/)
>     
>    [- (Command Line Tool (Xcode 9) - for macOS 10.12)](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.12_for_Xcode_9/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.12_for_Xcode_9.dmg)
>     
>    [- (Command Line Tool (Xcode 9) - for macOS 10.13)](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.13_for_Xcode_9/Command_Line_Tools_macOS_10.13_for_Xcode_9.dmg)
>
> For non-premium account/apple id: (Download Xcode 9.3.x without Paid (Premium) Apple Developer Account from below link)
>
> - [Xcode 9.4 (Mac App Store Link)](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?ls=1&mt=12)

**Update**

According to your updated question, you are using Xcode 9.0.1 and your provisioning profiles/certificates were working with Xcode 9.0.

Here is temporary solution for your problem: There is no huge difference between Xcode 9.0 and Xcode 9.0.1. Develop your code in Xcode 9.0.1 and create a build from Xcode 9.0.

Comment: I've seen, there an issue with distribution procedure in Xcode 9.0.1, so you may use Xcode 9.0 to distibute your app